# Why do I get - Failed to resolve com.squareup.retrofit2: retrofit:2.3.0

Tags: android, gradle

Here is my code, I am follwing a tutorial on making a login for my app but when I got to this stage I get errors.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.sqaureup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.sqaureup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The spelling of square word is wrong, so change it to this:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
```